# Laravel get model ID before saving

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I get the ID for the next record so I can pass it to a custom payment gateway, and only save if the payment is successful?

So far, I create the transaction and pass the ID to the payment gateway. Unfortunately, this saves the transaction in the database even if the payment is unsuccessful.

```
public function makeDeposit($amount, Pool $pool, $payment_method_id, $payment_number, $user_id)
    {
        if ($payment_method_id === 1) {
            $deposit = Transaction::create([
                'pool_id' => $pool->id,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'amount' => $amount,
                'payment_method_id' => $payment_method_id,
                'transaction_type' => 'deposit',
            ]);

            $result = $this->depositWithCustomGateway("XMZDEP" . $deposit->id, $payment_number, $amount, "XMZDEP" . $deposit->id);

            if ($result->status == 200 || $result->status == 201) {
                return $deposit;
            } else {
                throw new TransactionException($result->response->output_ResponseCode . " - " . $result->response->output_ResponseDesc, $result->status);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use database transactions.

Comment: How about just delete the transaction if it unsuccessful ? I mean, you already save it either success or not. If it is success, then it already saved. If it not, then delete it ?

Comment: @clover1234 He would still need to get the id to delete it.

Comment: @Innovin I know, but regarding his code above. He doesn't need an id. In his else statement, he could just $deposit->delete() if the payment is unsuccessful, and then throw the exception.

Comment: @clover1234 True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to go about this would be to save the item, then get the id,  After passing the ID to the gateway, if it is unsuccessful, you then delete it from the database. If it is successful, you just let it be.
In CODE:

```
$deposit = Transaction::create([
                'pool_id' => $pool->id,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'amount' => $amount,
                'payment_method_id' => $payment_method_id,
                'transaction_type' => 'deposit',
            ]);


$transactionId = $deposit->id(); // you now have the id



// Now pass the id to your payment gateway and if unsuccessful, you delete it from the database

$deposit->delete();
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of it that way. Will give it a try.

Comment: Just an update, worked like a charm.